# Different look for bundle-product

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I need to apply a different style for the bundle-products within a magento-project. And I'd like to know which would be the best routine to do so?

- Changing the layout with the layout updates directly in the dashboard
- Making a new layout-template explicitely for these products and apply
  this layout on all bundles

I have severally (>20) bundled products and want to use a quite different look for these. What would be the best routine therefore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it just styling changes, or differences at the page template level? If it's just styling, you can create custom CSS using the .bundle-product selector to apply the changes to bundle product types only. If you want to customise on the product level, the body tag will include a class built from the product identifier (e.g. product-type-my-amazing-product), which again you can target to apply styling changes on a per-product level.

For template overrides on the other hand, you'll need to use layout updates using the corresponding layout handles:

```
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <action method="setTemplate">                 
                <template>catalog/view/bundle.phtml</template>
             </action>
        </reference>
   </PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>
```

And then create the catalog/view/bundle.phtml file in your custom theme. Again, the same can be achieved on a per-product level: a product page can be targeted for a layout update using the layout handle  where X is the (numeric) ID of your product.